# How to remove subfolder name from Next Js URL?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created bunch of files in pages/user/ folder. I can access them with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/user/signup
http://localhost:3000/user/signin
http://localhost:3000/user/profile
```

What I would like to do is remove user/ part so that URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/signup
http://localhost:3000/signin
http://localhost:3000/profile
```

I will be adding more folders inside pages later for posts etc. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use a custom `server.js`. See the [Custom server and routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing) part of the documentation.

Your code would look something like this:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/signup') {
      app.render(req, res, '/user/signup', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/signin') {
      app.render(req, res, '/user/signin', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
```

Another option is to move the files themselves within the `./pages` folder, but I suspect you want to avoid doing this (hence your question).

Comment: Ya this works but requires manually typing all the routes. Is there a better solution?